# jquery adding prices together

Tags: jquery

Morning,
I am having an issue adding up some totals using jQuery.

I am passing the following in to this...

- Price - 600.00
- Shipping - 4.05

However i am getting the following results...

> subTotal = 600
>   productShipping = 4.05
>   orderTotal = 4.05600

```
 $.each(result, function (index, res) {
                var price = 600.00; //res.productPrice;

                var subTotal = res.itemQty * price;
                var orderTotal = res.productShipping + subTotal;

                new_record = "<tr>" +
                             "<td class=\"totals\">Sub Total</td>" +
                             "<td>£" + subTotal + "</td>" +
                             "</tr>" +
                             "<tr>" +
                             "<td class=\"totals\">Shipping</td>" +
                             "<td>£" + res.productShipping + "</td>" +
                             "</tr>" +
                             "<tr>" +
                             "<td class=\"totals\">Order Total</td>" +
                             "<td>£" + orderTotal + "</td>" +
                             "</tr>";

                $('#orderTotals').append(new_record);
```

I have a feeling there might be some issues with my jQuery adding up these items, however i can work it out. Could someone please shed some light on where i am going wrong.

res is the response i am using from the webservice call.

Many Thanks.

Comment: looks like your'e having string concatenation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` will concatentate strings as well as add together numbers. As you're getting concatentation, we can assume that `res.productShipping` is a string.

Therefore parse it to a float before adding up:

```
var orderTotal = parseFloat(res.productShipping) + subTotal;
```

Comment: that's cool, works great. how about the sub total? that seems to remove the .00 on the price.

Comment: if `subTotal` is numeric, you should be able to use `.toFixed(2)` on the end to always format with 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping `res.productShipping` in `parseInt()` or `parsedouble()` (or similar) when you use it to create `ordertotal`?

It sounds to me like it's trying to add them together as strings - therefore concatenating them - rather than adding the numbers together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var orderTotal = parseFloat(res.productShipping) + parseFloat(subTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert price to numbers by using parseInt and then perform the calculation.